# Value of an array does not change in call by address

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

In this program new value will be added to the array at end. When the memory is reallocated why it is not reflected back to the actual parameter

```
#include<stdio.h>
void insertion(int* arr,int *n)
{
    int val,n1=*n;
    int *temp;
    printf("\nEnter element to append");
    scanf("%d",&val);
    temp=malloc(sizeof(int)*n1);
        for(i=0;i<n1;i++)
        {
        temp[i]=arr[i];
        }
    n2=n1+1;
    arr=malloc(sizeof(int)*n2);
    for(i=0;i<n1;i++)
    {
        arr[i]=temp[i];
    }
    arr[n1]=val;
    *n=n2;
}
int main()
{
    int n=4;
    int arr[4]={1,2,3,4},i;
    insertion(arr,&n);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++) 
    {
        printf("\t%d",arr[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Changing `arr` in `insertion` changes only the local variable, not the `arr` in `main`.

Answer (score 1):

There are two reasons for this.

First, you're assigning the return value of `malloc` to `arr`, which is a parameter to the function and therefore local.  This means that changing the value of `arr` isn't reflected in the calling function.

Even if you fixed this, you would have a problem because `arr` in `main` is an actual array allocated locally, so you can't change its size.

You would first need to change `arr` in `main` to be a pointer and to allocate space for it with `malloc` so that you can use `realloc` later, and you need to change `insertion` to take a `int **` so that the actual pointer value in `main` can be changed.

Comment: why it becomes local when i assign value of malloc to arr ? , the paramter is actual so why not memory gets changed in main?

Comment: @VishnuChithan `arr` is already local because it's a parameter to the function. You use `*n=n2;` later in the function so it seems you understand that you need to dereference a pointer to change what it points to.  You would need to pass it as `int **arr` to the function then use `*arr = malloc(...);` to change the pointer in `main` (once you change the variable in `main` to a pointer).

Answer (score 1):

Because the parameter is passed by value.

You change `arr` in `insertion`, there's no reason that should change `arr` in `main`. They're different variables. This is how C works.

But in main `arr` is an array, which means it couldn't be changed even if you got the code right.

Here's how to do it right, if you want to change something in main you have to *return* the vaue from your function.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int* insertion(int* arr,int *n)
{
    ...
    return arr; // return the new value of arr
}

int main()
{
    int n=4;
    int* arr = malloc(n*sizeof(int)); // arr is a pointer, not an array
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) 
        arr[i] = i+1;
    arr=insertion(arr,&n); // get the returned value from insertion
    for(i=0;i<n;i++) 
    {
        printf("\t%d",arr[i]);
    }
}
```